# Most up to date environment for classic ASP development

Tags: windows, ide, asp-classic, development-environment

I've inherited a Classic ASP application that requires some maintenance.

What's the most up to date/capable IDE and Operation System that I can use to perform this maintenance?

I'll be setting up the Env in a VM - so won't be tied to it full time.  Hopefully there's something newer than Visual Interdev for me to use.  Ideally I'm hoping for some code completion and a debug capability.

Cost is of interest, but is not a deciding factor.

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to setup a VM, since all you need is Visual Studio 2008 and IIS installed in your dev machine (Presumably you have both already installed if you are a .net developer).

Be sure to install VS2008 SP1 for proper ASP Classic intellisense support.

Comment: Great answer Ed,
you're suggesting software about 10 years newer than I was expecting to use!

I'll give it a go.

cheers,
Ian

Comment: Ian: beware the ASP classic support is an optional (no default) installation in Windows Vista and 7 IIS, so remember to tick to checkbox.